# Use scroll-spy to change the navbar background classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am working on a web page in Bootstrap 4, that has sections with light and dark backgrounds and a fixed navbar. The navbar is dark (has the css class `bg-dark`) and, while it is easily visible against the light sections, it is indistinguishable *against the dark* ones.

I have added Bootstrap's scroll-spy to the page, but what *it* does is add the `active` class to the navbar items, as seen below:

```css
.page-section {
  padding: 70px 10px
}

.page-section.bg-dark * {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="15">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="section1" class="container-fluid bg-light page-section">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="container-fluid bg-dark page-section">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="container-fluid bg-light page-section">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

How can I change the navbar's `navbar-dark bg-dark` to `navbar-light bg-light` when the user reaches div with id `section3` or (even better) with **class** `bg-light`?

Comment: You may want to look at some of the options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237406/animate-shrink-navbar-on-scroll-using-bootstrap-4/42250478#42250478

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way to change the target of the active class, so you're left with a javascript option.  Fortunately, Bootstrap 4 does provide an event that gets triggered when a new active item is set.  One odd quark with it is that the documentation suggests you can add the listener event to the element with `data-spy`.  This does not work.  You have to add it to the `window` object (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48694139/854246).  Here's a code snippet:

```js
$(window).on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function (e,obj) {
    // spy changes to the last item at the end of the page,
    // so we want to avoid changing the class at this point.
    // Spy still works, but we want the class to be based on
    // whatever block was closest.
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/40370876/854246
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        return;
    }

    // Here we detect the targets class.  I'm just using bg-
    // light.  Not the most robust solution, but it can be
    // tweaked.
    var isBGLight = $(obj.relatedTarget).hasClass('bg-light');
    // note that navbar needs two classes to work.  If you
    // only set bg-light/bg-dark, the link text color doesn't
    // change.
    $('.navbar').toggleClass('navbar-dark bg-dark', isBGLight)
                .toggleClass('navbar-light bg-light', !isBGLight);
});
```

```css
.page-section {
  padding: 70px 10px
}

.page-section.bg-dark * {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="15">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="section1" class="container-fluid bg-light page-section">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="container-fluid bg-dark page-section">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="container-fluid bg-light page-section">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

<strike>I would make this a stack snippet, but Stack Overflow doesn't like it when you listen to events on the `window` object for security reasons (sandboxed iframe and whatnot), so here is a fiddle demonstrating this solution:</strike> *Apparently it does support it.  It just doesn't like when you use `console.log`*

https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/jzg7ok0v/

Comment: Great! But what if the sections have no ids *and* the links look like this: `<a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact page</a>`?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir You'll need a new solution then, unfortunately.  [According to the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#how-it-works), spy requires anchors that "must point to an element with [an] id."

Comment: Is that solution a 100% custom one, or is there a plugin to use?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir It's a custom solution using what's already provided by bootstrap.  jQuery is a dependency of bootstrap, so that should already be there.  If you're using scroll-spy, there should be no other dependencies needed.  As for, plugins, I'm not personally familiar with any that fits this particular need.  Are you having trouble implementing the above code?

Answer (score 1):

here a test with you need, but for scroll for 1 px and after begining the change for some states. sorry my bad english.

https://codepen.io/jhonycertz/pen/eQPbXy

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var isScrolled = $(document).scrollTop() > 1;
    $('.menu').toggleClass('nav_white', isScrolled);
  
$(window).on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function (e,obj) {
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
   return;
  }
 var Transparent = $(obj.relatedTarget).hasClass('nav_transparent');
  var White = $(obj.relatedTarget).hasClass('nav_white');
  var Blue = $(obj.relatedTarget).hasClass('nav_blue');
  $('.nav').toggleClass('nav_transparent', Transparent, !White, !Blue)
              .toggleClass('nav_white', White, !Transparent, !Blue)
              .toggleClass('nav_blue', Blue, !Transparent, !White);
});
  });
```

```css
.page-section {
  padding: 70px 10px
}
.move{
  background-color:#000
}
.page-section.bg-dark * {
  color: #fff;
}
.transparent{
  background-color:green;
}
.nav_transparent{background-color:yellow;}
.nav_white{background-color:grey;}
.nav_blue{background-color:black;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".nav" data-offset="15">
  <nav class="menu nav navbar navbar-expand-sm nav_transparent fixed-top">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
     <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section">Section 0</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-none">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section4">Section 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="section" class="container-fluid bg-light page-section">
    <h1>Section 0</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section1" class="container-fluid bg-light page-section nav_transparent">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="container-fluid bg-light page-section nav_blue">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="nav_white container-fluid bg-dark page-section">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section4" class="nav_blue container-fluid bg-light page-section">
    <h1>Section 4</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use js code for toggle class

```js
 $(window).on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function (e,obj) 
{
   if(document.querySelector(obj.relatedTarget).classList.contains('bg-light'))
   {
      $('.navbar').removeClass("navbar-dark bg-dark");
      $('.navbar').addClass("bg-light navbar-light" );
   }
   else
   {
      $('.navbar').removeClass("bg-light navbar-light");
      $('.navbar').addClass( "navbar-dark bg-dark" );
   }
});
```

```css
.page-section {
  padding: 70px 10px
}

.page-section.bg-dark * {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="15">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="section1" class="container-fluid bg-light page-section">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="container-fluid bg-dark page-section">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="container-fluid bg-light page-section">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```